# Jquery Mobile - Set Global Timeout

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

All,

Since every link (that is a href tag) is treated as an Ajax Request in Jquery Mobile, how do we set global timeouts since a link can take a min 2-3 mins to render?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify.  Not such what you mean by "a link can take 2-3 mins to render."

Comment: In Jquery mobile, every link is treated as an ajax request. So, if i have something like this, <a href="abc.html">click me</a>, the html file may have lots of content and might take atleast 2-5 minutes to load.

Comment: I would redesign the site as 2 to 3 minutes is probably over wifi, think about a edge connection, sheeeeeesh

Comment: Get a better back-end. Any length of html should be generated in less than a minute. And a page that's supposed to be served to a mobile should get generated in less than 3s. Unless you really ment `render` and it's the time it takes to draw the html - then it's a bl..dy mess :)

Comment: And to support my point here comes a more serious paper: http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set global properties for `$.ajax()` requests using the `$.ajaxSetup()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Comment: I tried to change that on line 6413 of jquery-1.5.2.js by adding timeout:300000, but still it didn't work